# Extending d3.selection in v5—is this the correct way to do it?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, prototype

**Background:** I was trying to solve the problem of appending existing local `SVG` files to a `d3` SVG container in an `Electron` desktop app. I discovered that I can't use `d3.svg()` on local files because `fetch` does not work with the `file` protocol (so said the error msg).

I came across this [gist](https://gist.github.com/biovisualize/373c6216b5634327099a) referenced by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40038305) for extending `d3.selection` and it appears to do exactly what I need, adding `appendHTML` and `appendSVG` functions.

When I tested the code though  (at bottom below), it threw an error: "Cannot read property 'prototype of undefined" – choking on this line:

```
d3.selection.enter.prototype.appendHTML
```

I dug around a bit through logging to the console and came up with this change and it seems to work:

```
d3.selection.prototype.enter.prototype.appendHTML
```

**My Question:** Am I doing this right? Did something change in `d3` which necessitates the additional `prototype` reference? I'm no Javascript or d3 hero and would like to understand what the difference is here.

```
d3.selection.prototype.appendHTML =
    d3.selection.prototype.enter.prototype.appendHTML = function (HTMLString) {
        return this.select(function () {
            return this.appendChild(document.importNode(new DOMParser().parseFromString(HTMLString, 'text/html').body.childNodes[0], true));
        });
    };
```

---

Original code

```
 d3.selection.prototype.appendHTML =
    d3.selection.enter.prototype.appendHTML = function(HTMLString) {
        return this.select(function() {
            return this.appendChild(document.importNode(new DOMParser().parseFromString(HTMLString, 'text/html').body.childNodes[0], true));
        });
    };


 d3.selection.prototype.appendSVG =
    d3.selection.enter.prototype.appendSVG = function(SVGString) {
        return this.select(function() {
            return this.appendChild(document.importNode(new DOMParser()
            .parseFromString('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + SVGString + '</svg>', 'application/xml').documentElement.firstChild, true));
        });
    };
```

Comment: To go back to the Q that prompted the research, could you have your Electron app running a little server and then fetch local files using their locations wrt: wherever you have defined the `localhost` root to be?

Comment: @ialarmedalien thanks. I didn't want to add the complexity of starting a local server, if at all possible. Seems like this extending `selection` works really well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers you mentioned are using D3 v3, but things have changed considerably from v3 to v4/v5. The main difference when it comes to selections is covered by just one sentence in the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection):

> Selections no longer subclass Array using prototype chain injection; they are now plain objects, improving performance.

Although this sounds quite simple it nonetheless required vast changes under the hood. All selection objects are now instances of the [`Selection`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/index.js) function which is not directly exposed. [`d3.selection`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/index.js#L39-L41) is a function returning a new instance of a `Selection`:

```
function selection() {
  return new Selection([[document.documentElement]], root);
}
```

Although both `Selection` and `d3.selection` share the same [prototype](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/index.js#L43-L75), which  contains the `.enter` property, there is no property `.enter` unless an instance is created, hence the error in your code.

The correct way of extending D3's selection objects in v4/v5 would be along the following lines:

```
d3.selection    
  .prototype    // This prototype is shared across all types of selections.   
  .appendHTML = // Apply changes to the selection's prototype.
```

Since the `prototype` property of `Selection` and `d3.selection` points to the same object, these changes will affect both normal as well as enter selections because they are both instances of the `Selection` function.

As you can see, this is just the first line of your own code, which is perfectly fine. Your extension using `d3.selection.prototype.enter.prototype.appendHTML` only kind of works: it does neither harm nor good! Setting the property on the `.enter` function is pointless as there is never an instance created from this function.

Have a look at the following working demo which I adopted from the gist you linked to in your question:

```js
d3.selection.prototype.appendHTML =
  function(HTMLString) {
    return this.select(function() {
      return this.appendChild(
        document.importNode(
          new DOMParser().parseFromString(HTMLString, 'text/html').body.childNodes[0], true)
        );
    });
  };

d3.selection.prototype.appendSVG =
  function(SVGString) {
    return this.select(function() {
      return this.appendChild(
        document.importNode(
          new DOMParser()
            .parseFromString('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + SVGString + '</svg>', 'application/xml').documentElement.firstChild, true));
    });
  };

d3.select('.container').appendHTML('<svg><g><rect width="50" height="50" /></g></svg>');

var svg = d3.select('.container')
  .appendHTML('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><circle class="circle1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle></g></svg>')
  .select('g');

svg.appendSVG('<circle class="circle2" cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>');
svg.appendSVG('<rect width="30" height="30"></rect>');
```

```css
div,
svg {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 10px;
}

rect {
  fill: skyblue;
}

.circle1 {
  fill: orange;
}

.circle2 {
  fill: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a clear answer. I do have one question though (of course...). The method I came up with seems to work: `
d3.selection.prototype.enter.prototype.appendHTML`   Is the difference that I am extending the `selection.prototype` and you are extending an instance of it?

Comment: @NoGrabbing This answer got a downvote, which got me thinking... Although it wasn't plain wrong, it kind of missed the point and made it more difficult, than it really is. I have since adjusted the answer which now also sheds some light on why your original solution worked although it looked akward.

Comment: @NoGrabbing Side note: the way D3's selections are extended seems rather cumbersome. You could probably make your life a whole lot easier if you employed [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to insert custom markup.